# create hightlighted words in red in argument column showing 2 in count(*) column

Tags: mysql

[image: 1]

I want to see those two create hightlighted words in red in argument column showing 2 in count(*) column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(argument, ' ', 1) as FN, COUNT(*) 
FROM mysql.general_log
GROUP BY FN
```